# hazelcast objects destroy mechanism

Tags: java, garbage-collection, hazelcast

my `hazelcast` version is 3.4.1.

I use `Locks and Maps` via `hazelcast`.I find that the heap memory on `hazelcast` server keep increasing.All the `Locks and Maps` I created  are destroyed by method `destroy()`,but the memory can not be destroyed by garbage collector even via FGC.So when my program run for some time,`hazelcast` server will go down.

Why?

My code looks like this:

```
 ILock lock=hazelcastInstance.getLock("host"+hostId);
 lock.lock();
 try { //do host businesses }
 finally{ lock.unlock(); lock.destroy(); }
```

I dumped the heap,and find that `Locks and Maps` has been destroyed.However, many other objects related to `Locks and Maps`  are not been destroyed.So the more new `Locks and Maps` I create,the faster the heap increases.

There are the kind of object relavant still exist in heap when I destroy `Locks and Maps`:

1.`ConcurrentMap<ObjectNamespace, EntryTaskScheduler>` evictionProcessors in LockServiceImpl

2.`ConcurrentMap<ObjectNamespace, LockStoreImpl>` lockStores in LockStoreContainer

3.`ConcurrentMap<String, LocalMapStatsImpl>` statsMap in LocalMapStatsProvider

Is this bugs of `hazelcast`?  or `hazelcast` does not support the scene that keep creating  new `DistributedObject`s and destroy them?

[image: heap]

[image: evictionProcessors]

[image: lockStores]

[image: statsMap]

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example that will reproduce this issue? Or show a relevant part of code that causes this issue?

Comment: like this: ILock lock=hazelcastInstance.getLock("host"+hostId);
  lock.lock();
  try{
   //do host businesses
  }finally{
   lock.unlock();
   lock.destroy();
  }

Comment: Hi @MinYang you have created a ticket on our github https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/7246, so probably best to continue the discussion here.

Comment: @pveentjer  ok.I ask here because i have trouble with uploading image on gihub.so i try it here.

Comment: No problem. I have added the link to this website.

Comment: @pveentjer I write a simple project which can reproduce this issue.https://github.com/yangmin1989/hazelcast-test